# Extract values from oddly-nested Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I must be really slow because I spent a whole day googling and trying to write Python code to simply list the "code" values only so my output will be Service1, Service2, Service2. I have extracted json values before from complex json or dict structure. But now I must have hit a mental block.

This is my json structure.

```
myjson='''  

{  
     "formatVersion" : "ABC",  
     "publicationDate" : "2017-10-06",  
"offers" : {  
"Service1" : {  
  "code" : "Service1",  
  "version" : "1a1a1a1a",  
  "index" : "1c1c1c1c1c1c1"  
},  
"Service2" : {  
  "code" : "Service2",  
  "version" : "2a2a2a2a2",  
  "index" : "2c2c2c2c2c2"  
},  
"Service3" : {  
  "code" : "Service4",  
  "version" : "3a3a3a3a3a",  
  "index" : "3c3c3c3c3c3"  
    }  
  }  
 }  
'''  
#convert above string to json
somejson = json.loads(myjson)
print(somejson["offers"]) # I tried so many variations to no avail.
```

Comment: What's odd about this? Looks like a perfectly normal nested dict to me; the only slight unusualness is that `offers` is also a dict, rather than a list.

Comment: The copy / paste works perfectly for me. What's wrong, what did you expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somejson["offers"]` is a dictionary. It seems you want to print its keys.

In Python 2:

```
print(somejson["offers"].keys())
```

In Python 3:

```
print([x for x in somejson["offers"].keys()])
```

In Python 3 you must use the list comprehension because in Python 3 `keys()` is a 'view', not a list.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks. And how to list "version" values?

Comment: If you want to list any of the entries in the innermost dictionaries (the ones with `"code"`, `"version"` and `"index"`), you can do e.g. `print([x["version"] for x in somejson["offers"].values()])`. This was mentioned by @glenfant in his answer.

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you, Shaun.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you want the "code" stuffs :

```
>>> [s['code'] for s in somejson['offers'].values()]
['Service1', 'Service2', 'Service4']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do the trick , if you are not certain about the number of Services in the json.

```
import json
myjson='''  

{  
     "formatVersion" : "ABC",  
     "publicationDate" : "2017-10-06",  
"offers" : {  
"Service1" : {  
  "code" : "Service1",  
  "version" : "1a1a1a1a",  
  "index" : "1c1c1c1c1c1c1"  
},  
"Service2" : {  
  "code" : "Service2",  
  "version" : "2a2a2a2a2",  
  "index" : "2c2c2c2c2c2"  
},  
"Service3" : {  
  "code" : "Service4",  
  "version" : "3a3a3a3a3a",  
  "index" : "3c3c3c3c3c3"  
    }  
  }  
 }  
'''  
#convert above string to json
somejson = json.loads(myjson)


#Without knowing the Services:
offers = somejson["offers"]
keys = offers.keys()

for service in keys:
    print(somejson["offers"][service]["code"])
```

Comment: Everything as in? Code you show or give an example of the expected output?